# Windows Store Apps - Storage

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to read/write some text files from Local Storage:

```
KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary
```

I have a simple text file that is stored in 'Documents' in my OneDrive folder, and I can read that fine. But when I write out another text file it gets created in my local 'Documents' folder for my PC, not the OneDrive folder. Why is that when I'm pointing to the same folder for both reading and writing, it reads from one location, but writes to another?  Here is the method:

```
public static async void MyMethod()
{
        var myFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
        Stream myStream = await myFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("readFromHere.txt");
        string fileContents = "";
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(myStream))
            fileContents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        var outputFile = await myFolder.CreateFileAsync("writeToHere.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(outputFile, fileContents);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that isn't working correctly? Ideally a self-contained simple program.

Comment: Turns out this error IS happening on my work PC. I included the code up above.